# XMLHttpRequest access denied while trying to access files from web server location - IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, activex, activexobject

I am working on javascript where i am trying to access a url path using xmlhttprequest . the code works fine with activexobject ( i dont want to use activex object ) . when i try to call it using xmlhttprequest it does not work . it gives an error saying access denied. i am using IE8 version here . I have already tried the below workaround

- enabling the "access data sources across domain in internet option"
- adding trusted sites

```js
if(src) //scr = templates/mytemplate
{
 try{
 var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();   //new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); works fine 
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if(xhr.readyState==4)
{
  log.profile(src);
if(xhr.status==200||xhr.status==0)
{
 //do some action
}
}

element.html(xhr.responseText);
log.profile(src);
xhr.open("GET",src,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(null);
}}catch(e){
 alert("unable to load templates"+e); // here i am getting error saying acess denaied 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you got Access denied error. **Looks like you are directly trying to run the HTML page in IE browser. You need to host the web page on any web server.** for testing purpose, I hosted this sample page on IIS server. Than you can try to access the web page from IE will help to visit the page without this error.

I tried to make a test with this sample code and I tested it with IE 11 (IE-8 document mode).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "xmlhttp_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Based on my testing result, code is working fine with the IE-8 document mode so it should also work in IE-8 browser.